# How to get the standard deviation from gaussian fitted curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

How can I get the standard deviation from gaussian fitted curve in Matlab?

It's not an Output of `fit` function.

code:

```
[fy, god] = fit(xx, yy, 'gauss2');
```

output:

```
>> fy

fy = 

     General model Gauss2:
     fy(x) =  a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2)
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       a1 =    -0.09287  (-0.09414, -0.0916)
       b1 =        3805  (3805, 3806)
       c1 =        20.9  (19.8, 22.01)
       a2 =     -0.3454  (-0.3497, -0.3411)
       b2 =        3862  (3861, 3862)
       c2 =       19.32  (18.82, 19.82)
>> god

god = 

           sse: 2.7037e-04
       rsquare: 0.9995
           dfe: 55
    adjrsquare: 0.9994
          rmse: 0.0022
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of `fy` says that you are fitting a model that consist of a linear combination of two Gaussian functions. The functional form of the model is:

```
fy(x) =  a1*exp(-((x-b1)/c1)^2) + a2*exp(-((x-b2)/c2)^2)
```

Remembering that a Gaussian is defined as:

```
f(x) = exp(-(x-x0)^2/(2*s^2))      where: x0 is the mean, s is the std.dev.
```

then the standard deviation of each Gaussian in your model can be computed as (respectively):

```
s1 = c1/sqrt(2)
s2 = c2/sqrt(2)
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function for more infomation.